# Datetime format issues

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I am facing difficulty in converting string representation of date to datetime object. My string is `"2013424"` and if i use the following piece of code to convert string to datetime then it fails..

```
string format = "yyyyMd";
DateTime.TryParseExact("2013424", format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dtAnswerDate);
```

> dtAnswerDate does not contain converted representation of string
>   value.

But if my string has value like `"20130424"` then it works fine. Any possible suggestions please?

The value comes from Microsoft HealthVault using an XPath expression in my code. This XPath expression is provided by the end user. The XPath expression selects a node and uses the InnerText property to return value. I am writing the below code for reference.

```
string strItemXML = healthRecordItem.GetItemXml();
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(strItemXML);
XmlNode xpathNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
When = healthRecordItem.LastUpdated != null ? healthRecordItem.LastUpdated.Timestamp : healthRecordItem.EffectiveDate;
if (xpathNode != null)
{
    return xpathNode.InnerText;
}
```

'strItemXML' contains the below XML

```
`<thing>  
<thing-id version-stamp="a40f8c41-0329-4b0f-af56-33040a1f3ecf">de631835-c7b6-43dd-9ae9-528c26ab2204</thing-id>  
<type-id name="Appointment">4b18aeb6-5f01-444c-8c70-dbf13a2f510b</type-id>  
<thing-state>Active</thing-state>  
<flags>0</flags>  
<eff-date>2013-04-23T14:33:00Z</eff-date>  
<created>  
<timestamp>2013-02-15T12:48:42.74Z</timestamp>  
<app-id name="InstantPHR Personal Health Record">afc8707e-c160-4b7f-9856-69d5c790b1a9</app-id>  
<person-id name="Mohammed Owes">f848a184-878d-4cef-999f-dff54d2e5db2</person-id>  
<access-avenue>Online</access-avenue>  
<audit-action>Created</audit-action>  
<master-app-id>8df99894-5f36-489a-a8fd-ffe6b25b8efb</master-app-id>  
</created>  
<updated>  
<timestamp>2013-04-24T07:44:58.38Z</timestamp>  
<app-id name="InstantPHR Personal Health Record">afc8707e-c160-4b7f-9856-69d5c790b1a9</app-id>  
<person-id name="Mohammed Owes">f848a184-878d-4cef-999f-dff54d2e5db2</person-id>  
<access-avenue>Online</access-avenue>  
<audit-action>Updated</audit-action>  
<master-app-id>8df99894-5f36-489a-a8fd-ffe6b25b8efb</master-app-id>  
</updated>  
<data-xml>  
<appointment>  
<when>  
<date>  
<y>2013</y>  
<m>4</m>  
<d>24</d>  
</date>  
<time>  
<h>14</h>  
<m>33</m>  
<s>0</s>  
</time>  
</when>  
<service>  
<text>RREEESSSTTTT</text>  
</service>  
<clinic>  
<name>  
<full>Mohammed Owes</full>  
</name>  
</clinic>  
</appointment>  
<common>  
<source>InstantPHR</source>  
<extension source="phr.getrealconsulting.com.appointment_v2"/>  
</common>  
</data-xml>  
</thing>`
```

and 'xpath' value is "/thing/data-xml/appointment/when/date". So my code will return you "2013424"

Comment: you did not specify the language, you did not provide a self sufficient working example for people to help you, please edit your answer.

Comment: You can find alot ways to format your string check this page: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/ or use string.format http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

Comment: You can find alot ways to format your string check this page: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: @MohammedOwes Looks like you have the values separated. I'm not hot on xpath, but I'd suggest reading the year / month / day individually and stitching them together yourself (or even just creating a date time straight from them: `new DateTime(year, month, day)`, instead of reading just from the parent date.

Comment: @dannywalls: The links you posted can help if i have the datetime object and if it needs to be converted to string but in my case its the other way round.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I had your idea in my mind but i cannot use that option as the code for returning Xpath's InnerText value is generic one which may return date value, string value, integer value etc. I cannot have the user give three different XPath as there is only one textbox for the user to enter an XPath to retrieve value. So the user can either enter "/thing/data-xml/appointment/when/date/y" for year or he can enter "/thing/data-xml/appointment/when/date" to get complete inner text value which includes year, month and date.

Comment: @MohammedOwes Is there anyway to amend the xml document beforehand? This way you can make all day and month values 2 digit, which would also remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth i am afraid that the XML document cannot be amended as that is controlled by Microsoft HealthVault. So can i assume that there is no way i can achieve what i intend to.

Comment: @MohammedOwes More text boxes to select the date parts? Otherwise, you're getting more stuck with each limitation :-(

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth no extra textboxes to select date parts.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Looks like you have the values separated in that xml.

You can avoid parsing altogether by extracting the year, month, and day separately and feeding that into the `DateTime` constructor that takes those three arguments:

```
var date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Unfortunately, I'm not too hot on XPath so you'll have to amend that part yourself.

---

I think the problem here is potential ambiguity with what numbers go into month or day. I know the date you use as an example is not actually ambiguous, but it still fails because the potential is still there.

For example: 2013111. Is this November 1st, or January 11th? This is why the leading 0 works, because it can segregate the digits to remove ambiguity.

I don't think there is a way to get this format to work unless you add white-space or specify leading zeroes.

White-space example:

```
string format = "yyyy M d";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("2013 4 24", format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You haven't stated any limitations or where the "2013424" value comes from, so I can't easily suggest a way to get around this issue that is specific to your code.

Of course, if you don't catch the value in a non-ambiguous format from the point of input, *you will also hit these ambiguity problems* in trying to understand what is a day and what is a month.

For reference, [you can find the documentation for `DateTime` format strings here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: I have edited my question and have also explained where the value comes from. Maybe now it is sufficient to understand the situation.

Comment: I had your idea in my mind but i cannot use that option as the code for returning Xpath's InnerText value is generic one which may return date value, string value, integer value etc. I cannot have the user give three different XPath as there is only one textbox for the user to enter an XPath to retrieve value. So the user can either enter "/thing/data-xml/appointment/when/date/y" for year or he can enter "/thing/data-xml/appointment/when/date" to get complete inner text value which includes year, month and date.

Answer (score 1):

Your best solution is probably to make sure you get the two-digit representation of the month before trying to convert it; I'm assuming of course, that you are concatenating the various parts of the original date, and that it is not provided as `2013424` originally (that would make the date ambiguous).

I.e something like:

```
var monthString = (monthString.length > 1) ? "0" + monthString : monthString;    
var dateString = yearString + monthString + dayString;
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, out dtAnswerDate);
```

*Update:*

It's still a little unclear to me why you can not fetch mont by itself, but if this is in fact the case, then there is basically no good solution for you. The following are examples of ambiguous dates: `2013111, 2013211, 2013129`.

**You simply cannot parse the date safely, if you don't know wheter a specific digit is a part of the representation of a month or of a day.**

Is there perhaps some other logic to this, which you have not mentioned? Can you think of any way to safely "guess" how a digit should be interpreted? Or maybe you can limit or manipulate the XPath expression a user can use in some way?

If not, then I'm afraid there simply is no safe solution to your problem.

Comment: I cannot format the month to two-digit representation as the value comes from another source as mentioned in my edited version of question.

Comment: I've updated my answer (although it's probably not quite what you were hoping for.. :\ )

Comment: Yes, but atleast i came to know that i cannot represent my string to datetime object unless i use a two-digit representation for month or use separator between year, month and date. Still thank you for letting me know that there is no way to do what i wanted to do.